# Из модели в DropDownList на View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть у меня две модели:

```
public class Ue_model
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    [Key]
    public int Id { set; get; }
    [Display(Name = "Модель")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Column(TypeName = "char")]
    public string Model_Name { set; get; }
    public int UetypeId { set; get; }
}

public class Ue_type
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    [Key]
    public int Id { set; get; }
    [Display(Name = "Тип")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Column(TypeName = "char")]
    public string Type_Name { set; get; }
}
```

чтобы с ними работать с двумя объединил их во `ViewModel`

```
public class ModelViewModel
{
    public int ModelId {  get; set;}
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public string ModelType { get; set; }
}
```

Все отлично, но как мне сделать `DropDownList` во `View`?

```
  var result_list = (from m in db.Ue_model
          join t in db.Ue_type
          on m.UetypeId equals t.Id
          select new ModelViewModel
          {
               ModelName = m.Model_Name,
               ModelType = t.Type_Name,
               ModelId = m.Id
          }).ToList();
```

Мне получается нужно вывести `ModelType = t.Type_Name` список типов модели, как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас уже есть поле `Type_Name`, в котором будет отображаться выбранное значение в `DropDownList`. Вам необходимо в модель, которая приходит в представление добавить поле, содержащее список Ваших типов:

```
public class ModelViewModel
{
    public int ModelId {  get; set;}
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public string ModelType { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> NameTypes { get; set; } // новое поле
}
```

Либо вместо коллекции строк использовать [SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460123(v=vs.108).aspx)

Просто в контроллере проинициализируйте и заполните данное поле типами модели, думаю просто из базы достать все уникальные или лучше написать отдельный метод, который будет давать Вам этот список.

```
private List<string> GetTypeNames()
{
    // берем все уникальные значения из db.Ue_type
}
```

Затем, внутри метода контроллера необходимо присвоить значение

```
public ActionResult [имя Вашего метода]()
{
    // допустим такой код (пример)
    var model = new ModelViewModel();
    // код заполенния значений модели...
    // ...
    model.NameTypes = GetTypeNames(); // просто заполняем это значение
    // так как у Вас там список в модели, то код нужно будет немного модифицировать

    // а затем уже отправляем заполненную модель на представление
    return View(model);
}
```

А затем, внутри представления нужно будет использовать `DropDownListFor`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Type_Name, model.NameTypes)
```

Таким образом Вы отобразите выпадающий список.

Полезные ссылки для рассмотрения:

1. [SelectListItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.aspx)
2. [SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703462.aspx)

Comment: Не совсем понимаю Вас.

Comment: @shatoidil, добавить поле с типом в модель, как я написал. Внутри метода контроллера, где Вы делаете `return View(model)` необходимо перед возвратом заполнить `model.NameTypes`, который Вы добавите в модель. К примеру `model.NameTypes = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3"}`. А затем внутри представления, там где раньше Вы отображали `Type_Name` впишите строку с `DropDownListFor`, которую я Вам написал.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Мне добавить именно в модель? не в ModelViewModel?

Comment: @shatoidil, ну судя по Вашему коду, то в `ModelViewModel` :)

Comment: Я страшно извиняюсь, но ничего не выходит(. Делаю все как указано выше в контроллере, но при попытки NameTypes = m.Model_Name, ошибка ,что он не может конвертировать стринг в айнумерейбл. И все

Comment: @shatoidil NameTypes - это коллекция, прочтите внимательно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44087/discussion-between-denis-bubnov-and-shatoidil).